# How to "bounce back" in "bounce ball" equations?

Tags: physics, simulation

How to "bounce back" in "bounce ball" equations?

Or "reverse the trajectory shape" after a hit?

http://reactorlab.net/resources-folder/matlab/pdf-link-folder/bouncing_ball_equations.pdf

I don't see whether they do it in the paper.

By looking the plots one'd guess that one takes the inverse function so that the shape reverses. However, I have no idea whether this is physically accurate way of doing it.

Comment: If you assume perfect elasticity and that the ball is a point mass then just define it piecewise by taking the position and momentum of the ball at the (first) exact moment it hits whatever surface you're concerned with, and calculating a new "bounce ball" equation for it from the same position but with momentum reflected across the surface, and repeat. At each time point where a collision occurs you move to the next function.

Comment: @JackCrawford What you mean "reflected"?

Comment: @JackCrawford I don't even see whether they actually explain the "bounce back" in that paper.

Comment: So, technically, in this paper their ball is only moving in one direction; up and down. The horizontal axis on their graph is time, not actual horizontal movement, so if you are asking how you make it "bounce back" from a wall, well, it'll never hit a wall, since it's only bouncing up and down in place. But if you modified it so the horizontal axis actually was horizontal motion, and parametrised the 2d position in terms of time, then you just have to solve for the time when the ball hits the x pos of the wall and then just recalculate a new path from there but negate x component of velocity

Comment: @JackCrawford Can you point out where they reverse the "shape" of the trajectory? Because I cannot understand it. Intuitively it's in "% now ball bounces", but I don't understand it.

Comment: At the exact moment that the collision occurs (which you can solve for algebraically) they take the velocity and make it negative. This is what a bounce is. That's all you have to do in the one-dimensional case (bouncing off the floor, as in this paper). If you want a ball to move in 2d space and be able to bounce off both walls and surfaces, you do the same thing except you only negate the component of the velocity that is perpendicular to the wall.

Comment: @JackCrawford Maybe I did something wrong then, because when I reversed the sign of the "g"-term, then it didn't mirror the shape, rather the trajectory is "concave up" after the hit. Or maybe the key is that I need to do the "piecewise" thing so that I start a new function computation at every "hit".

Comment: yeah, you don’t want to negate $g$, that’s acceleration. you want to calculate the velocity at the point of impact and negate that.

Comment: @JackCrawford Ahh now I see how the curve is formed.